# Bootstrap 4 container not taking full height when used in React

Tags: html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to use Bootstrap 4 in React. How can I make the container take up 100% height?

HTML in my React component:

```
<div className="container h-100"> 
    <div className="row">
        <div className="col-md-6" />
        <div className="col-md-6" />                               
    </div>
</div>

<div className="filler" />
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    background-color: green;
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
}

.filler {
    background-color: orange;
    height: 2400px;
}
```

I would like for container (green portion) to take up 100% height. Currently, it wraps around the content (the navbar, which was created as a separate React component).

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYn91.png)

I've been able to get containers and divs to take on the 100% height in plain Bootstrap html / css. But when I insert the same code into my React component, the height doesn't end up working. I'm able to set the width to 80% and the height to either px or vw, but I can't seem to set the height to a percentage. I've also tried using flex-container, which didn't solve the issue.

Would appreciate any help!

Comment: have you tried 100% height on `body` tag as well?

Comment: I have, although I don't currently use the body tag anywhere.

Comment: i have the same issue here

Answer (score 0):

Would changing container height: 100% to min-height: inherit help?

```
return (
    <>
        <div style={{minHeight: "60px"}} className="bg-info">

            <div className="container" style={{backgroundColor: "green", width: "80%", minHeight: "inherit"}}> 
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-6">Home</div>
                    <div className="col-md-6">About...</div>                              
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div style={{backgroundColor: "orange", height: "2400px"}}/>
    </>
)
```